# Bypass cfthread & event gateway limit in CF standard edition with Java 7 thread pool?

Tags: coldfusion, java-7, coldfusion-10, threadpoolexecutor

On paper it seems that together with CF10's [dynamic proxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ff9.html) and optionally with [Java 7 Thread Pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html), it is now possible to [define Runnable in CFC](https://github.com/lmajano/messaging-polyglot/blob/master/consumer/cfml/start.cfm) and a thread pool respectively purely in CF.  If this works, wouldn't this essentially bypass the cfthread / event gateway [limitations in CF Standard](http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/coldfusion-family/buying-guide.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation is on `<cfthread>`, not on "usage of threads in general":

> On Standard Edition, the maximum limit of threads that can be spawned via CFTHREAD is 10

(From "[Adobe ColdFusion 11 family / Buying guide : Product comparison](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/coldfusion-family/buying-guide.html)")

You're using a different mechanism to do your threading, so it would be absolutely fine.